# Why does my right sidebar only go up halfway the screen?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to figure out why my right sidebar only goes half-way up the screen and what I'm doing wrong. 
I have the HTML and CSS at the bottom and a picture of the website at the bottom. I'm trying to get the text in the middle but when I do that the text blocks the right sidebar from going all the way up. I have a picture of what it's supposed to look like at the bottom also. I could really use some help with this.

[image]

```css
/* right sidebar */
#right_sidenav {
  width: 180px;
  float: right;
  background-color: #F5DEB3
  padding: 0;
}

/* the styles for the section */
html {
  background-image:url(../images/bats.gif);
  background-repeat: repeat;
}
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  width: 800px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 5px solid black;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 5px black;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
section {
  width: 600px;
  float: right;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-bottom; 20px;
}
main {
  clear: both;
}
aside {
  width: 160px;
  float: left;
}
section h2 {
  margin-left: 0;
}
section figcaption {
  float: right;
  clear: right;
  margin-left: 10em;
  padding-right: 15em;
}
section img {
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<section>
    <h2>20" Deranged Cat</h2>                 
        <figure>
            <picture>
                <img src="images/cat1.jpg" alt="cat">
            </picture>

            <figcaption>This cat provides its own light and is perfect for a
            backyard haunting.
                Price 19.99</figcaption>
        </figure>
</section>
<div id="right_sidenav">
<h5>Customers who bought this product also bought:</h5>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <figure>
                <picture>
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/flying_bats.jpg" alt="flying bat"></a>
                </picture>
                <figcaption>
                    <a href="#">Flying bats</a>
                </figcaption>
            </figure>
        </li>
        <li>
            <figure>
                <picture>
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/rat1.jpg" alt="rat"></a>
                </picture>
                <figcaption>
                    <a href="#">16" Ugly rat</a>
                </figcaption>
            </figure>
        </li>
        <li>
            <figure>
                <picture>
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/strobe1.jpg" alt="strobe light"></a>
                </picture>
                <figcaption>
                    <a href="#">Mini strobe light</a>
                </figcaption>
            </figure>   
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

'#' usually stops a sidebar when you go to it. Only classes will work with this.
You also need to define everything. Style is not defined. No content is the `<style>` tags are defined either.

When you have a tag in html and want to define it with CSS then you do not put a '.' in front of the class as it is a tag not a class

```
 <section>
            <h2>20" Deranged Cat</h2>                 
                <figure>
                    <picture>
                        <img src="images/cat1.jpg" alt="cat">
                    </picture>

                    <figcaption>This cat provides its own light and is perfect for a
                    backyard haunting.
                        Price 19.99</figcaption>
                </figure>
        </section>



<div id="right_sidenav">
        <h5>Customers who bought this product also bought:</h5>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <figure>
                        <picture>
                            <a href="#"><img src="flying_bats.jpg" alt="flying bat"></a>
                        </picture>
                        <figcaption>
                            <a href="#">Flying bats</a>
                        </figcaption>
                    </figure>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <figure>
                        <picture>
                            <a href="#"><img src="images/rat1.jpg" alt="rat"></a>
                        </picture>
                        <figcaption>
                            <a href="#">16" Ugly rat</a>
                        </figcaption>
                    </figure>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <figure>
                        <picture>
                            <a href="#"><img src="images/strobe1.jpg" alt="strobe light"></a>
                        </picture>
                        <figcaption>
                            <a href="#">Mini strobe light</a>
                        </figcaption>
                    </figure>   
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>





/* right sidebar */
#right_sidenav {
width: 180px;
float: right;
background-color: #F5DEB3
padding: 0;

/* the styles for the section */
html {
    background-image:url(../images/bats.gif);
    background-repeat: repeat;
}
li {
list-style: none;
}
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    width: 800px;
    background-color: white;
    border: 5px solid black;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 5px black;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
section {
    width: 600px;
    float: right;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-bottom; 20px;
}
.main {
    clear: both;
}
.aside {
    width: 160px;
    float: left;
}
.section h2 {
    margin-left: 0;
}
.section figcaption {
    float: right;
    clear: right;
    margin-left: 10em;
    padding-right: 15em;
}
.section img {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```